How can I print the product of this function?
when I try to print the code below I get <function get_length at 07fbee3b94e188>
def get_length(string):
  counter = 0
  for letter in string:
    counter += 1
  return counter

get_length("parangaricutirimicuaro")
print(get_length)

How can I print the lenght of the string in the function instead of getting that weird code?

Assign the return value to something, and then print the return value. I don't normally answer in comments, but this question is really basic and likely to get closed.

You are printing function object. To print result of function:
result = get_length(“string”)
print(result)

As well you can use built in function ‘len’
print(len(“qwerty”))

